# How to access fields of Json object in Angular component [Angular 11]

Tags: angular, typescript, angular11

Here is the method from my Angular service calling a simple REST API:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Token } from './Token';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TokenServiceService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getToken(code:any):Observable<Token> {

    const url = 'http://example.com/token?code='+ code +'&state=STATE123';
    
    return this.http.get<Token>(url);
  }
}
```

Token:

```
export interface Token {
  some_val:String;
  some_val2:String;
  some_val3:String;
}
```

Here is the code snippet from the component that calls the above method:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Token } from '../Token';
import { TokenServiceService } from '../token-service.service';
import { GlobalComponent } from '../global-component'


@Component({
  selector: 'app-accesstoken',
  templateUrl: './accesstoken.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./accesstoken.component.css']
})
export class AccesstokenComponent implements OnInit {

  public token!:Token;
 
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private tokenService: TokenServiceService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {

    const code = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('code');

    this.tokenService.getToken(code).subscribe(data => this.token = data)
    console.log('obj : '+this.token)
    console.log(this.token.some_val)
  }
}
```

Console output **[here is the problem]**:

```
obj :undefined
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'some_val')
```

This tag in html successfully displays Json object (token) on UI:

```
<pre>{{token | json}}</pre>
```

But how can I access fields from token obj in my component class itself without displaying on GUI? I Want to set some fields to a browser cookies.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the problem is with the asynchronous nature of `.subscribe()` and Observables in general. In `AccesstokenComponent` your `console.log` lines are going to be called **before** the `this.token = data` assignment, which has to wait for the observable to get resolved. Calling the `subscribe` method doesn't make your code to wait for the execution of that observable, instead you can register the callback that's going to be invoked once the observable is ready. I bet if you put those logs inside the `subscribe` callback, after the assignment, you'd be able to see the contents of `this.token`.

EDIT:
You also want to render this token value in the template. For this purpose I'd recommend getting familiar with the [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) (basically if you make your field an `Observable<something>`, then you've got to call it in the template with `| async` to render it)